# UIWebView, determine if page has loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I would like to know when my WebView has finished loading a page. Im quite new to this and I wonder if you have any suggestions. I need to create a "Loading screen" while the page is loading. This is my basic code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.se";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933414/deferring-viewwillappear-until-webviewdidfinishload

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are *two* different callbacks when the view finishes loading, successful load and failed load. They are both part of the the [UIWebViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Implement it and set yourself as the delegate for your web view. Then implement

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

to know when the loading has finished, so that you can remove your loading screen, and implement

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

to know if it failed so that you can show and appropriate message to the user instead of an infinite loading screen.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the UIWebViewDelegate Protocoll. If you set your delegate, you receive messages like `– webViewDidFinishLoad:`

that's what you want, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I have poor experience with DOM but after some searching I found that the document.readyState is the great option.

From w3schools:

Definition and Usage
The readyState property returns the (loading) status of the current document.

This property returns one of four values:

uninitialized - Has not started loading yet
loading - Is loading
interactive - Has loaded enough and the user can interact with it
complete - Fully loaded

So I'm using this to know when UIWebView has loaded the document:

```
- (void)readyState:(NSString *)str
{ NSLog(@"str:%@",str);

if ([str isEqualToString:@"complete"]||[str isEqualToString:@"interactive"]) {
    NSLog(@"IT HAS BEEN DONE");
    [pageLoadingActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
 //other code...
 [self readyState:[browserWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str]];
}
```